# how to hide the previous pop up window when a new one is created in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, popup

I have a list of employees displayed on the screen. When I click on one of them, a pop-up window shows up and contains a list of the several actions that can be "done" on this employee (delete, modify ...).
When I click on an employee, the pop-up shows up correctly but when I click on a another one, the new pop-up window is appended to the previous one.
Here is how I did:

```
    employee.click(function(){   //employee is a javascript variable 
          createPopUp(taskActions, mainDiv); //taskActions is an array of strings
     });

     function createPopUp(taskActions, parentDiv) {
     var popUp = null;
     if (taskActions.length != 0) {
        popUp = $('<div style="z-index:2;position:fixed;display:inline-block;border-style:solid;border-color:black;text-align:center;margin:0px;padding:2px;background-color:white"/>');
        for (var i = 0; i< taskActions.length; i++) {
           function createAction(i) {
              var actionDiv =  $('<div>' + taskActions[i]+ '</div>');
              actionDiv.on('click', function(event) {
                 //doSomeAction
               });
              popUp.append(actionDiv);
         }
         createAction(i);
      }
      parentDiv.append(popUp);
   }
}
```

I know I have to hide the pop-up window somewhere in createPopUp.  And most likely right before appending the popUp to the parentDiv. But when I do like that, the popUp doesn't show up anymore.

What's wrong here?

Thank you for your help

Comment: is parentdiv responsible for only showing the popup? can you do parentDiv.empty() before appending the popup?

Comment: parentDiv is responsible for showing the name of the employee as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add a class to the `div` and remove all elements with that class prior to adding the new `div`:

```
$('.popup').remove();
popUp = $('<div class="popup" style="z-index:2 // etc
```

Comment: I can do popUp.remove() without adding a class. And that's what I've tried to do. But it didn't fix the problem. Doing that doesn't allow me the display any pop-up

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kmvhd/4/) I knocked up to prove that it works.

Comment: works awesome. thanks :) But do you know what is the difference between popUp.remove() (which didn't work for me), and $('.popup').remove() ?

Comment: `$('.popup').remove();` is the jQuery selector that grabs all of the elements of class `popup` and removes them. `popUp.remove();` would remove the element that you've created, but since you were adding it before you created it I guess it did nothing. Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `createPopup` function return the jQuery object:

Then whenever you make one, store the reference to it, so that you can remove it later:

```
(function(){
  var $popUp;
  employee.click(function(){   //employee is a javascript variable 
    if($popUp) $popUp.remove();
    $popUp = createPopUp(taskActions, mainDiv); //taskActions is an array of strings
  });
})();

function createPopUp(taskActions, parentDiv) {
    var popUp = null;
    if (taskActions.length != 0) {
        popUp = $('<div style="z-index:2;position:fixed;display:inline-block;border-style:solid;border-color:black;text-align:center;margin:0px;padding:2px;background-color:white"/>');
        for (var i = 0; i< taskActions.length; i++) {
           function createAction(i) {
              var actionDiv =  $('<div>' + taskActions[i]+ '</div>');
              actionDiv.on('click', function(event) {
                 //doSomeAction
               });
              popUp.append(actionDiv);
         }
         createAction(i);
      }
      parentDiv.append(popUp);
   }
   return popUp;
}
```

Comment: it is still doesn't work. the popUp.remove is never executed. popUp is always null. with the chrome debugger, it shows that the returned value popUp is not empty, but the test if ($popUp) always fails

Comment: @user1499220 Are you sure you copied it correctly? It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bm9St/

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work in your jsfiddle. that's exactly the same behavior that I have. Every time you click on the button, a new pop-up is appended to the previous one ..

Comment: @user1499220 Perhaps this will make it more clear (http://jsfiddle.net/Bm9St/4/) what's going on. There is only ever one popup. I was just appending to the contents of the popUp to demonstrate that each popUp was different.